# Fujitsu Lifebook 280dx

Tags: discussion, scope

Would questions on the hardware and upgrades of a Fujitsu Lifebook 280dx be on-topic?  Its an Pentium 233 MHz laptop that shipped with NT/95.

Answer (score 2):

While technically the Lifebook 280 may be considered on-topic, RC.SE might not be the perfect environment for the question, as it's a standard PC in a closed setup, not really hackable beside adding the provided modules, the docking staions or changing the single memory module (up to 96 MiB max).

The [manual](http://www.fujitsupc.com//www/content/pdf/usermanuals/200series/270_80dx.pdf) already tells all that's possible.

Comment: That answer sounds like "hackability" would be a criterea for fitness of a topic here. I don't think so (and I guess that's not what you wanted to say).

Comment: @tofro Yes - and no. You're of course right, that hackability on its own is in no way an indicator for RC.SE. But in context with the mentioned laptop is acts as a qualifier. The 280 is a standard design right out of Intels manual pages, modular but closed. So there isn't much to be asked about the machine itself or it's upgrades that isn't either about standard PC issues (which woudn't be about the 280), or where to buy replacements (which is OT anyway).